# How to compare between values in two diffrent JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

```js
   

 const fruits = [{id: '1', name: 'Apple'},
    {id: '2', name: 'Orange'},
    {id: '3', name: 'Cherry'}];

    const food=[{id: '1', food_name: 'Orange', deleted:"0"},
    {id: '2', food_name: 'Bread' ,deleted:"0"},
    {id: '3', food_name: 'Cheese', deleted:"0"},
    {id: '4', food_name: 'Apple', deleted:"1"},
    {id: '5', food_name: 'Salt',deleted:"0"}
    ]
    //Code that I tried:
    var dep_data = [];
var foodSet = new Set(food.map(item => item.food_name));

for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++) {
  if (!foodSet.has(fruits[j].name) && fruits[j].deleted !== "1") {
    dep_data.push({ id: fruits[j].id, name: fruits[j].name });
  }
}
    console.log(dep_data)
```

I want to compare between two arrays to get the id and name of the fruits that not exists in the food and deleted not equal to 1 then save the results in new array.

For example here we have the Orange exist in the food array, the results should store the id and name of fruits that doesn't exist in food and deleted !=1. (Apple, cherry).

Comment: So what is the problem in current code ? Here, `apple` and `orange` exist in `food` array. Only `cherry` does not exist in `food` array, and it is being saved in `dep_data` array. According to the condition you described, your code seems to be working !

Comment: @PK_ IT MUST TO STORE THE CHERRY BECAUSE NOT EXISTS AND THE APPLE BEACAUSE DELETED=1 MY CODE NOT WORKING IN THIS SCENARIO

Comment: In your question you have stated the condition as `doesn't exist in food and DELETED != 1`. Also, in your code you have put the condition as `departments[j].deleted!=='1'`. Now you are saying you want `deleted=1`. First make your mind clear about whether you want `DELETED=1` or `DELETED!=1`, and make appropriate changes in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has syntax errors, here is the updated one:

```js
const fruits = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Apple' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Orange' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Cherry' }
];

const food = [
  { id: '1', food_name: 'Orange', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '2', food_name: 'Bread', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '3', food_name: 'Cheese', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '4', food_name: 'Apple', deleted: "1" },
  { id: '5', food_name: 'Salt', deleted: "0" }
];

var dep_data = [];
var foodSet = new Set(food.map(item => item.food_name));

for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++) {
  if (!foodSet.has(fruits[j].name) && fruits[j].deleted !== "1") {
    dep_data.push({ id: fruits[j].id, name: fruits[j].name });
  }
}

console.log(dep_data);
```

The result will return an array object containing `cherry`

Comment: I don't have deleted property in the fruits

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is almost correct. There's just one small mistake in the comparison of the deleted property. Instead of comparing it to the string "1", you should compare it to the number 1. Here's the corrected code:

```
const fruits = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Apple' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Orange' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Cherry' }
];

const food = [
  { id: '1', food_name: 'Orange', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '2', food_name: 'Bread', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '3', food_name: 'Cheese', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '4', food_name: 'Apple', deleted: "1" },
  { id: '5', food_name: 'Salt', deleted: "0" }
];

const dep_data = [];
var foodSet = new Set(food.map(item => item.food_name));
for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++) {
  if (!foodSet.has(fruits[j].name) && fruits[j].deleted != '1') {
    dep_data.push({ id: fruits[j].id, name: fruits[j].name });
  }
}
console.log(dep_data);
```

The output will be:

```
[ { id: '1', name: 'Apple' }, { id: '3', name: 'Cherry' } ]
```

This means that the fruits "Apple" and "Cherry" are not present in the food array and have deleted not equal to 1, so they are stored in the dep_data array.

Comment: it must to use the id instead of name