# How to compare between two values in json - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to compare between two arrays to get the id and name of the fruits that not exists in the food and deleted not equal to 1 then save the results in new array.

```
const fruits = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Apple' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Orange' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Cherry' }
];

const food = [
{ id: '1', food_name: 'Bread', deleted: "0" }
  { id: '2', food_name: 'Orange', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '3', food_name: 'Cheese', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '4', food_name: 'Apple', deleted: "1" },
  { id: '5', food_name: 'Salt', deleted: "0" }
];

const dep_data = [];
var foodSet = new Set(food.map(item => item.id));
for (var j = 0; j < fruits.length; j++) {
  if (!foodSet.has(fruits[j].id) && food[j].deleted != '1') {
    dep_data.push({ id: fruits[j].id, name: fruits[j].name });
  }
}
console.log(dep_data);
```

For example here we have the Orange exist in the food array and deleted = 0, the results should store the id and name of fruits that doesn't exist in food and deleted not equal to 1. (Apple, cherry).
Note: the comparison should be based on the ids and not on names.

Comment: `&& fruits[j].deleted != '1'` - its not your items in `fruits`, that have a `deleted` property.

Comment: A `Set` does not have a method to access a specific entry, using a `Map` would make more sense here IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe please check the code I have edited it

Comment: _"the comparison should be based on the ids and not on names"_ - but `Orange` has id 2 in your first array, and id 1 in the second ...? Sorry, but I can't make sense of this.

Comment: @CBroe sorry for this mistake . please check the code now

Comment: This is still not making sense. _"of fruits that doesn't exist in food and deleted not equal to 1. (Apple, cherry)"_ - Cherry does not exist in food, but Apple does. Apple _does_ have deleted=1, so why should it be part of the result then?

Comment: Just seeing now, that this is actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76251175/how-to-compare-between-values-in-two-diffrent-json-array

Answer (score 0):

why so easy. is there nothing more difficult? lol

```js
const fruits = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Apple' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Orange' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Cherry' }
];
const food = [
  { id: '1', food_name: 'Bread', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '2', food_name: 'Orange', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '3', food_name: 'Cheese', deleted: "0" },
  { id: '4', food_name: 'Apple', deleted: "1" },
  { id: '5', food_name: 'Salt', deleted: "0" }
];

const dep_data = [];
food.forEach((e,i) => {
  dep_data[i] = e
  if(e.deleted == 0) delete dep_data[i].deleted
  fruits.forEach((j,k) =>{
     if(j.id == e.id) dep_data[i] = Object.assign(dep_data[i], j)
  })
})
console.log(dep_data);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  // Create a map to store names from arr2
  const nameMap = new Map();
  
  // Populate the name map with names from arr2
  for (const item of arr2) {
    nameMap.set(item.food_name, true);
  }
  
  // Compare names from arr1 with the name map
  for (const item of arr1) {
    if (nameMap.has(item.name)) {
      console.log(`${item.name} is present in both arrays`);
    } else {
      console.log(`${item.name} is not present in arr2`);
    }
  }
}

compareArrays(fruits, food);
```